# div goes top when I close on widget - Jquery dragable

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery-Ui for Jquery draggable for one of my website. Here is my fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nb8dLq7m/) . I can add multiple widgets to the screen. It works fine but when I close any one and try to drag other the widget position gets changes to top of the document. How can I prevent the widget to change it position to top ?

Here is my script,

```
var widgetId = 0;
$("#btnAddWidget").click(function () {
                $("#container").append('<div class="Widget" id="widget' + widgetId + '"><input type="button" class="close" id="btnclose' + widgetId + '" value="Close" /><input type="button" class="addgraph" id="btnAddGraph' + widgetId + '" value="Add Graph" /></div>');
                widgetId++;
                $(".Widget").draggable({
                    containment: '#container',                    
                    cursor: 'move',
                    start: function (event, ui) {
                        // Show start dragged position of image.

                        var Startpos = $(this).position();
                        if (Startpos.top < 0) {
                            debugger;
                            $(this).css("top", 0);
                        }
                    },

                    // Find position where image is dropped.
                    stop: function (event, ui) {
                        // Show dropped position.
                        var Stoppos = $(this).position();                        
                        if (Stoppos.top < 0) {
                            debugger;
                            $(this).css("top", 0);
                        }
                    }
                });
                $(".Widget").resizable({ containment: 'parent', });
            });

            function setPositionToRelative(element)
            {

            }

            //Close Button Event Binding or Delete Widget
            $(document).on('click', '.close', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //when delete widget position set to absolute of other widgets
                $('.Widget').each(function () {
                    var top = $(this).position().top + 'px';
                    var left = $(this).position().left + 'px';
                    $(this).css({ top: top, left: left });
                }).css({ position: 'absolute' });

                $(this).parent().remove();

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First answer or add this to your css if you want to manually drop the widgets to the top.

```
#container {
    height: 500px
}
```

or

```
#container {
    min-height: 500px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed this piece of code from your fiddle:

```
$('.Widget').each(function () {
   var top = $(this).position().top + 'px';
   var left = $(this).position().left + 'px';
   $(this).css({ top: top, left: left });
}).css({ position: 'absolute' });
```

I'm pretty sure removing that will give you the results you're looking for. This function was being called on close click and was giving each `.widget` element undesired css properties.

Hope this helps.